Опросник на модальных окнах
Как можно реализовать вот такую вещь:
Пользователь на сайте открывает модальное окно Bootstrap заполняет input'ы, затем есть выбор.
1)Закрыть окно и сохранить данные (улетят в базу).
2)Нажать на кнопку в модальном окне, открывается второе модальное окно, также с заполнением input. И таких переходов пользователь может сделать n количество пока пользователь не нажмет сохранить.
Как бонусом, пользователь может возвращаться обратно к предыдущим окнам для редактирования внесенных данных.
В Bootstrap есть "Переключение между модальными окнами", но там нужно будет заранее указать количество модальных окон. А не то количество которое создаст пользователь.
Вероятно выход лежит через jquery, но как сделать, нету опыта.

https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/zbhqt3vw    ......... https://codepen.io/Obazee/pen/gVezQr

Вам точно необходима модалка после моделки? Ведь что бы вернуться с 5 на 2 придется закрывать 3. Может проще использовать в модалке что то типа бутстраповских "Табов"?  Тогда пользователь сможет легко вернуться на любой шаг назад, но не сможет перейти вперёд (так как будет стоять запрет) пока не заполнена текущая форма

Кстати, да, можно использовать одну модалку, получается просто менять формы при заполнении одной, формируется другая и.т.д, а как сделать создание этих форм в n количестве? Пользователь, когда создано опрос может сгенерировать от 1 до 30 вопросов. Как сделать чтобы он при необходимости создавала эти формы с вопросами в том количестве, которое ему нужно.
